# Why isn't AVPlayer playing .wav file

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer

I am downloading a .wav file from a server and storing it locally in the file system. Once the file has been downloaded I try and play the file using the `AVPlayer`.

The url of the file being stored is something like this:

`/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FC767376-76BC-4402-B51B-SDFS/data/Containers/Data/Application/FA18B9RE-8D6E-4553-0617-4A064478AFF4/Documents/voice/test.wav`

I have gone through all the related questions and have checked that I am doing the following:

- Keeping reference to the `AVPlayer` in the viewController
- Setting the category on the `AVAudioSession`
- Setting the `AVAudioSession` to active
- using `NSURL(fileURLWithPath:)` to retrieve the file url
- I have tried using `AVAudioPlayer`

I have also confirmed the url being set on the AVPlayer does infact contain the audio file.

I have generated a test project that reproduces this issues. It can be found at https://github.com/va3093/AVAudioTest

Is it the way that I am storing the file? Is there something wrong with the file formats?

Comment: Have you tried with different files of the same and different formats? Is the file you're trying to use corrupted in transit (i.e. can it be opened as-is on your computer?) Have you tried using an actual device?

Comment: I have tried on an actual device and it still didn't play. I haven't tried different formats. Those files do open on VLC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the webservice I was using to generate the audiofiles genertate `.mp3` files while I was saving them as `.wav`. When I changed to `.mp3` then the audio player started playing the audio files.